# How to typeset micro fonts?

Tags: positioning, margins, fontsize, printing

Here is the scenario: I'm having a exam and I'm allowed to take 1 printed/written page (cheat sheet) to exam. I want to prepare a cheat sheet with small fonts utilizing the entire page.

1. I tried using the document without headers (`\maketitle`) and still
   there are margin spaces left blank that I would like to fill up as
   well. I would like to use the entire page and divide the page into
   several parts and fill each parts - just like a table with multiple
   row and columns. The font wont go below 10pt.
2. I would like to have may be 6pt (I'm not sure)?

Any help on achieving this wil be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Prepare it with A3 paper (package `geometry`) and normal fonts and reduce it to A4 at print time. This will scale everything at 70.7%, so 10 point fonts would become effectively 7pt.

Comment: Using a sharp pencil will be faster and allows you to fill the available white space much more effectively.

Comment: Use the time, you’d need for setting, for learning instead. ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=6pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol,microtype,color}
\columnsep=2pt
\begin{document}\parfillskip=2pt \parindent=0pt
\begin{multicols}{3}
\textcolor{red}{Part1}\lipsum\hrule\lipsum\hrule\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

You can also use tabular(x) or `\parbox` to generate parts. But it will more difficult to avoid white spaces.